# How to find the inverse of this complicated function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

Hi I've been trying to figure out this algebra problem and have gotten nowhere. I'm trying to find the inverse function of this function.

$f(x)=\dfrac{c^\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}{x}}x-ck\ln\left(\frac{\left|\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}{x}}-\sqrt{c}\right|}{\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}{x}}+\sqrt{c}}\right)}{c^\frac{5}{2}}$

I'm looking to find $f^{-1}(x)$

If it helps $f(x)=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{-2k}{x}+c}} dx$

I can find the inverse functions of certain parts of the right side, but I'm unable to do it as a whole. I was wondering if this is even possible to solve!? Thanks!

Comment: The easiest thing to do is cancel the $c^{\frac 52}$ in the denominator... say $g(x)=c^{\frac 32}f(x)$.  Then you can write $g(x)=\sqrt{c^2x^2-2ckx}-k\ln\left(\dfrac{|\sqrt{cx-2k}-\sqrt{cx}|}{\sqrt{cx-2k}+\sqrt{cx}}\right)$.  Other things after that are not so easy, but you can modify the fraction inside the $\ln$ by $\dfrac{|\sqrt{a-b}-\sqrt a|}{\sqrt{a-b}+\sqrt a}=\dfrac {|-b|}{\left(\sqrt{a-b}+\sqrt a\right)^2}$.

Comment: Given how complicated this is, do you have reason to believe that the function has an inverse?

Comment: No, but I don't know how to prove there isn't. It would be also be helpful to find.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it would be helpful to find this inverse?  Is this homework?  Do you have to prove that no inverse exists?

Comment: It has local inverses. However, you may not find a nice closed expression for it in terms of elementary functions. I suggest letting $$u = \sqrt{c - \frac{2k}x}$$ and inverting it first in terms of $u$. Solving for $x$ from $u$ is easy.